# jQuery determine if a tag is empty

Tags: jquery

I've almost got this but just need a little push over the edge. I'm parsing a string which contains (potentially) HTML. Here's the code:

```
function clean(snippet) {
   OBJ = $(snippet);
   txt = OBJ.text();

    if(txt) { 
      parsed = txt;
    } else {
        parsed = snippet;
    }
    return parsed;
}
```

And here are my test cases:

```
alert(clean("<div>Randomness</div>")); // Alerts "Randomness"
alert(clean("Randomness"));            // Alerts "Randomness"
alert(clean("<div></div>"));           // Alerts "<div></div>" - should be blank
```

I can't really figure out how to determine if its just an empty tag that gets passed in vs just plain text and how to deal with it. So I need a test to see if a tag is empty, perhaps. Not sure if that's the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if your query returns any objects:

```
function clean(snippet) {
   OBJ = $(snippet);
   if(OBJ.length == 0)
      return snippet;
   txt = OBJ.text();
   return txt;
}
```

Comment: Pedantically, this is wrong.  What if snippet is null.  Then again, i've just realised you're still falling in line with @stomped's code.  so, @stomped, before you test Obj.length you should test if (obj != null), and its possible that if OBJ is not a string then calling text() will fail.  i.e don't forget to add some error handling

Comment: @David - the function will return `null` in that case - not throw an error. jQuery returns an empty collection (`$(null).length` is `0`). An interesting side effect, however, is `clean('div')` - it enables DOM selections (maybe that was the point though).

Comment: @kobi, actually, firstly my bad, was trying in a faulted enivironment :-( it doesn't return error, BUT i just tested (properly I hope!) and $(null) == $(document).  So OBJ.text() in that case would fall over.  I'm not arguing btw to attack your answer, just interested in this now :-)

Comment: I'm getting 0 for the latest version of jQuery (1.4.2), and 1 for older versions, which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

You're test that txt is not null. try this.

```
if (txt == '')
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have html you can do something like this:

```
root = $(snippet);
if (root.text().length > 0) {
  return snippet;
}
if (root.find(":first")) {
   return snippet;
}
```

This doesn't handle the case the first element inside the div is empty.