# Changing the background of table cells to different colors with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table like this:

[image: installment table]

I want to change the background color of the cells with the prices when i click on them (such as `addClass(on)` ), as you can see on the bottom-left corner, and also change the background color of the other cells too (such as `addClass(off)` ).

I don't want the other cells being effected (the ones with text and also different colors).

I also need to get the id of the row which the clicked cell belongs.

Here is the structure of a row.

```
<tr class="taksit" id="tek">
    <td><b>Tek Çekim</b></td>
    <td><?=$sontutar?> TL</td>
    <td><?=$sontutar?> TL</td>
    <td><?=$sontutar?> TL</td>
    <td><?=$sontutar?> TL</td>
    <td><?=$sontutar?> TL</td>
    <td><?=$sontutar?> TL</td>
    <td><?=$sontutar?> TL</td>
</tr>
```

I have tried a few tricks found on here, but not able to do it.
Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Please show the representative HTML (of the table in your picture), *not* the server-side script that generates it: jQuery works *client-side*, what happens server-side is almost entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table#uniqueID tbody td').on('click',function() {
    $(this).closest('tbody').find('td').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: It works, but this code also changes the background of the colored cells which are on top.

Comment: Updated to focus on the `tbody` instead of the whole table. You may need to explicitly wrap the row containing those colored cells in a pair of `<thead>` tags.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much. But, How can I grab the id the of the closest row? I need get the "tek" value and give it to a variable.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest -- to retrieve the ID, use `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id')`

Comment: That's great. Thanks again. Just one more thing, Am I able to exclude the cells with no value (shown with a "-")? I don't want any color change when I click on the cells with no value. Is this possible?

Comment: Not easily. I would suggest posting that as a separate question. [This question might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324772/jquery-determine-if-a-tag-is-empty).

Comment: @ser - If you add a class to the "empty" cells marking them as empty, you can easily exclude them from any selector with [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

Comment: @Lix I've added a class to empty cells and changed the code like: `$('table#taksit tbody td'):not('.empty').on('click',function() {`but it doesn't work.

Comment: You only use `:not` within the selector -- change to the method [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not) in your example.

Comment: You're right, now It works. I really appreciate for your help guys. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#table_selector td.clickable").on('click',function(){
  // cache $(this)
  var clickedElement = $(this);

  // remove background color from other clickable items 
  $("td.clickable").css('background','none');

  // change the background color of the clicked <td>    
  clickedElement.css('background','red');

  var rowId = clickedElement.closest('tr').attr('id');
});
```

Let me explain a little bit about what I have done here.
First of all, you said that you don't want every `<td>` to be affected by these clicks and background changes. So you should give a class to all the `<td>`'s that are "clickable" and then you can limit your `on('click')` event to the elements you want. You could ofcourse also do the opposite, adding a "noClick" class to the ones you want to ignore...

Changing the background color of the `<td>` can be done in a few ways, I've chosen for the sake of example to use the simple `.css('background','red');`, but I'm sure you have some more logic in your actual code.

The `rowId` is extracted by looking for the closest parent element that is a `<tr>` using the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function. Then simply looking at the `id` attribute.